# Gtk#: Close current form after some idling time

Tags: c#, user-interface, gtk#

I should close secondary forms of my application and then I should open the main form after some idling time. Ofcourse, I can start Timer after form is loaded and reset it after each event, but what is the best way for solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a manager object with the timer there.  The manager object can manage when forms are stopped and started.  So, when the application is started, the "main" window is started by the manager object first.  When secondary windows are displayed, the manager knows this and starts the timer.  If this state persists for a preset amount of time, the manager's timer will go off and revert everything back (remove secondary windows and pop up the main window again).

When I say "window", that is the same as form.  Just so there's no confusion.